# Simple SQL query on one single table

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm ashamed but I must ask this `SQL` question. I'm actually using `SQLITE` on `Android`.

Let's assume there is only one table with 2 columns.

```
USER1 USER2 
111   555
111   300
445   111
555   111
325   111
111   233
300   111
```

I'd like to get the following results:

```
USER1 USER2
111   300
111   555
```

I tried `INNER JOIN` and `INTERSECT` but I could not get it to work.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Please add your query to your question.

Comment: `I tried INNER JOIN and INTERSECT ` show code.

Comment: Please explain what is the logic to get those two rows and not the others.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I do apologize for not adding my code and not explaining what I wanted to achieve in a better way. @arlh solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want rows where the switched user1/user2 also exist in the table. And also user1 < user2. Do a self join:

```
select t1.user1, t1.user2
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.user1 = t2.user2 and t1.user2 = t2.user1
where t1.user1 <= t1.user2
```

Comment: @jarlh  You should Accept this answer.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, it was jennie788 who asked the question.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you very much!!! Your answer solved my problem. 

My problem was that I used:

    join table t2 on t1.user1 = t2.user2

Instead of what you wrote:

    join table t2 on t1.user1 = t2.user2 and t1.user2 = t2.user1